# Connect handler to insert-text signal in GTK4

Tags: gtk, signals, textfield, gtk4

I'm trying to display something each time the user inserts something in an `Entry` widget. For instance, I have the following callback:

```c
void entry_text_inserted (GtkEditable* self, gchar* text, gint length, gint* position, gpointer user_data ) {
    g_print("Text inserted\n");
}
```

I connect it to the 'insert-text' signal:

```c
GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
g_signal_connect(entry, "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(entry_text_inserted), NULL);
```

However, this does not work: when running the application, the function `entry_text_inserted` is never called.

By contrast, connecting a handler to `changed` works perfectly: "Text changed" is correctly display whenever something happens to the text entry.

```c
void entry_text_changed(GtkEditable *editable, gpointer user_data) {
    g_print("Text changed\n");
}
```

```c
g_signal_connect(entry, "changed",     G_CALLBACK(entry_text_changed),  NULL);
```

**Question:** why is my callback to `entry_text_inserted` not called when I type something in the text entry?

Here is the full code:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// Callback function for handling text entry changes
void entry_text_inserted (GtkEditable* self, gchar* text, gint length, gint* position, gpointer user_data ) {
    g_print("Text inserted\n");
}

void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    // Create the main window
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK4 Entry Example");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

    // Create the Entry widget
    GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
    g_signal_connect(entry, "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(entry_text_inserted), NULL);

    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), entry);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize GTK
    gtk_init();

    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);


    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    return status;
}
```

Things I've tried:

- cast entry in `g_signal_connect` using `GTK_EDITABLE` and `GTK_ENTRY`: `g_signal_connect(GTK_EDITABLE(entry), "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(entry_text_inserted), NULL);`
- (superstitiously) move around the g_signal_connect statement to after the widget is added to the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4315) is a discussion of why it is not possible to connect the "insert-text" signal directly to a **Gtk.Entry**. Summarizing, **GtkEditable::insert-text** and **GtkEditable::delete-text** signals will be propagated from the “wrapper” editable to the delegate, but they will not be propagated from the delegate to the “wrapper” editable, as they would cause an infinite recursion.

If you want to use the signal, you will have to get the **Gtk.Editable** from the **Gtk.Entry** with `get_delegate()`, and connect the signal directly to the **Gtk.Editable**.

Comment: Wonderful, that was exactly that! I'm not fluent enough in GTK to understand the reasons behind this design quirk but, following the link's recommendation, one only needs to wrap `entry` as follows `gtk_editable_get_delegate(GTK_EDITABLE(entry))`, when connecting to the signal